# MYSQL TABLESPACE = innodb_file_per_table GIVING ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 168 from storage engine

Tags: mysql, innodb, tablespaces, mysql-5.7

I have tried this statement to place a tables in different disks. Operating system is Linux Oracle 7, I've changed permissions in the directory with `chmod -vR 777`, to have total access to the disk directory. I keep getting this error after running the following statement taken from mysql page directly

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (c1 INT PRIMARY KEY) TABLESPACE = innodb_file_per_table 
     DATA DIRECTORY = '/home/egonzalez/Documentos';
```

> ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 168 from storage engine

As far as I know, is a permission problem that mysql doesn't have access to the directory, but after changing permission in the directory I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I'm using mysql 5.7 that comes with oracle linux 7.

Comment: Where practical, it is better to use RAID "striping" to combine multiple drives.  This gives better performance in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the table created in that data directory with `.ibd` file, do this

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /home/egonzalez/Documentos
```

Then, run this

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (c1 INT PRIMARY KEY)
ENGINE=InnoDB DATA DIRECTORY = '/home/egonzalez/Documentos';
```

The option [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) is enabled by default in MySQL 5.7

The reason for the error in the first place ?

You need to run [`CREATE TABLESPACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-tablespace.html) like this

```
mysql> CREATE TABLESPACE `ts1` 
    ->     ADD DATAFILE '/home/egonzalez/Documentos/mytblspc.ibd' 
    ->     ENGINE=INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Then, you could create any table into be included in the one tablespace like

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (c1 INT PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=InnoDB TABLESPACE ts1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rolando. I had to leave the offic,. and now I´m at home. I'm setting up a virtual machine at home to try it out. Although it looks like you pointed me to the right place. My computer at home is kind of slow, so if I can´t try it out over the week end, I'll get you back on Mondey. I apretiate your help.